# Advanced Data Delimiter

Tags: excel

I have a log file with over 100,000 line of data and only about 5000 lines that I actually care about.  The rest is mostly junk like what is below.  It imports into Excel all as ~100K rows in one column and I can't delimit on anything.  The only thing I could do was search all "M-SEL" and change it to ";M-SEL" (same with the SAC line) and then that started to give me something to delimit on and to sort things out.  Is there a more elegant solution (VBA or Filter technique?) than what I listed above?

```
00:00:00                      M-SEL  802151  - - -   is supergroup
00:00:01                 SAC REJECT  - - -   800508  508 is not a valid     group id
```

Comment: How is the structure of the text file? Is the number of lines per record fixed and known? Or is the *Time* pattern a delimiter of the records?

Comment: One line per timestamp.  So in Excel it looks like ~100,000 rows and 1 column

Comment: The good news, as it seems, is that you have "two spaces" between different columns. If that's true the solution could be easy. Can you verify that?

Comment: It could be a `TAB` as well!

Comment: It is not a tab.  If it is multiple spaces, how would you delimit on that?  If I try to delimit on space, it chops everything up and becomes unusable.  I loaded it into Notepad++ and it shows no tabs and 23 spaces between the time and the next bit of text.  Now if I could delimit on 23 spaces, we would be all set!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the columns on the basis of multiple spaces with this macro:

```
Sub importLog()
    Dim record As String, i As Long, sh As Worksheet, len1 As Long, len2 As Long, ar
    Set sh = Worksheets.Add
    Open "C:\SO\mylog.txt" For Input As #1 ' <-- Enter your file's name here
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, record
        Do
            len1 = Len(record)
            record = Replace(record, "   ", "  ")
            len2 = Len(record)
        Loop Until len2 = len1
        If len1 > 1 Then
            i = i + 1
            ar = Split(record, "  ")
            sh.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, UBound(ar) + 1).value = ar
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great.  Thank you for the solution.